# Assign a variable to each line of the output and loop through it in bash

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

I have a command that will have multiple lines as output. i will need to use each line as a source to another Command to process it. i am trying to assign a variable and loop through it, but it fails

Here is the output from command line

```
r_mqsc -m ABCD -r "DIS CHL(*) WHERE(SSLCIPH EQ TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)" -l |awk '/Connected/,0'|grep -v Connected |awk -F'SSLCIPH' '{print $1}'

 CHANNEL(TO.MQ95XCAT02.SSL) CHLTYPE(CLUSRCVR)
 CHANNEL(TO.MQ95XRB01.SSL) CHLTYPE(CLUSSDR)
 CHANNEL(TO.MQ95XRC01.SSL) CHLTYPE(CLUSSDR)
 CHANNEL(TO.MQ95XRL01.SSL) CHLTYPE(CLUSSDR)
 CHANNEL(TO.MQ95XRN01.SSL) CHLTYPE(CLUSSDR)
 CHANNEL(TO.XA.MQ95XCAT02.SSL) CHLTYPE(CLUSRCVR)
 CHANNEL(TO.XB.MQ95XCAT02.SSL) CHLTYPE(CLUSRCVR)
 CHANNEL(TO.XN.MQ95XCAT02.SSL) CHLTYPE(CLUSRCVR)
```

Now each of these line (complete line as is) need to be input to another command

like this

```
r_mqsc -m ABCD -r "ALTER $VARIABLE SSLCIPH('123_ABC_XYZ')" -l
```

Here is my script, which is failing

```
_chl="$(r_mqsc -m MQ95XCAT02 -r "DIS CHL(*) WHERE(SSLCIPH EQ TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)" -l |awk '/Connected/,0'|grep -v Connected |awk -F'SSLCIPH' '{print $1}')"
chlcnt=$(r_mqsc -m MQ95XCAT02 -r "DIS CHL(*) WHERE(SSLCIPH EQ TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)" -l |awk '/Connected/,0'|grep -v Connected |awk -F'SSLCIPH' '{print $1}'|wc -l)
echo "$_chl"
set -A strqmgrs ${_chl}
i=$chlcnt
arrayindex=0
while [ i -ne 0 ]
do
 chl=${strqmgrs[$arrayindex]}

r_mqsc -m MQ95XCAT02 -r "ALTER $chl SSLCIPH('TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256')" -l

i=$((i-1))
 arrayindex=$((arrayindex+1))
done
```

the $chl variable is coming out like this

`ALTER CHLTYPE` -- > note it is just taking the word CHLTYPE in the actual output line but not the entire line.

Answer (score 2):

Don't write bash scripts the way you would write C code (nor vice versa).

```
cmd |\
while IFS= read -r line
do
  ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to keep variables set in the loop do it like this:

```
while read -r line 
do
  stuff

done < <( **command-line** )
```